# CommandTimeout not being used when WiFi drops

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, sqlclient

In the example below, the `CommandTimeout = 5` doesn't seem to help if the wifi connection is dropped. Unfortunately, the sqlConnection still has a `State` of `Open` even in this case.

The real issue is the timeout seems to be infinite, it just sits there .. hanging. I can't get it to return. Code after the `cmd_GetItem.ExecuteNonQuery()` is never called, it just hangs there.

Any ideas?

```
With cmd_GetItem
    .Connection = con
    .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .CommandText = "spGetItem"
    .CommandTimeout = 5
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScanData", Scan_Number)
    .Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
    .Parameters("@RecordCount").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
End With

Try
    MsgBox(con.State & " - " & con.State.ToString())
    cmd_GetItem.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'snip
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help with how some of the API functions work in special conditions, but with general approach:

Put the query in a separate thread and check if it ended with success after 'your' timeout definition. If the thread still runs (code hangs), the kill the thread and start over.

Something like this:

```
myThread.Start();
if( not (myThread.Join(timeout)) ) //this will block at max timeout
  myThread.Abort(); the thread is blocked!
```

Sorry, but no VB snippet.